# Showing that $|\phi(\mathcal{N})| = \kappa$ s.t. $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$ with $|\mathcal{N}| = \kappa$

Tags: logic, model-theory

**Problem:** Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is an $L$-structure and $\phi \in L_n$ ($n > 0$) is such that $\phi(\mathcal{M})$ is infinite.

Then show that for every cardinal $\kappa$ with $\kappa \ge |L|$ there is an $L$-structure $\mathcal{N} \equiv \mathcal{M}$ of power $\kappa$ and such that $|\phi(\mathcal{N})| = \kappa$.

**Attempt:**

1. Let $\kappa \ge |L|$.
2. By Lowenheim-Skolem (upwards or downwards, depending on the size of $|\mathcal{M}|$), we know that there exists a model $\mathcal{N}$ s.t. $|\mathcal{N}| = \kappa$ and whereby $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$.
3. It remains to be shown that $|\phi(\mathcal{N})| = \kappa$.
4. Now we can note that $|\phi(\mathcal{N})| \not < \omega$, since otherwise $\mathcal{N} \not \equiv \mathcal{M}$.  This is because the statement "$\phi(\mathcal{M})$ is not finite" is first-order, and hence since it's true in $\mathcal{M}$ it must also be true in $\mathcal{N}$ in order for $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$.  Hence $|\phi(\mathcal{N})|$ is infinite in $\mathcal{N}$.  But of course, $|\phi(\mathcal{N})|$ could still be greater or less than the size of $\kappa$.
5. So suppose that $|\phi(\mathcal{N})| > \kappa$.  This leads to a contradiction though, for the size of $|\mathcal{N}| = \kappa$ implies that any set of $n$-tuples from $N^n$ must also be at most size $\kappa$.  Hence since $\phi(\mathcal{N}) \subseteq N^n$ we have that $|\phi(\mathcal{N})| \le \kappa$.

**Question:** Finally, suppose that $\omega \le |\phi(\mathcal{N})| < \kappa$.    Then how would I either (i) show that this is impossible, or (ii) show that we can adjust $\mathcal{N}$ in such a way to make it impossible?

Comment: Can I suggest an alternative approach for a solution?

Comment: Sure -- I admit I might be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Well, Andre posted my idea, so I can safely go to sleep now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** I do not believe we can use Löwenheim-Skolem directly, we need to use the **proof** of Löwenheim-Skolem. We sketch the upward part. Add to the language $\kappa$ constant symbols $c_\alpha$, axioms that say they are different, and axioms that say that $\phi(c_{\alpha})$ holds for all $\alpha\lt \kappa$.  In the usual way, we show this has a model $\mathcal{N}$ of cardinality $\kappa$. It is automatic that $|\phi(\mathcal{N})|=\kappa$.

Comment: That was going to be my answer... :-) [Also should be noted that this is really just a use of compactness + the downwards theorem.]